# Merge [powerbi-datasource] into [powerquery]

Tags: support, tags

**Background Details**

Power BI is a self-service analytics tool. One of its defining features is the ability to extract data from just about any data source using a uniform language (PowerQuery M).

Stack Overflow has several related tags currently: [powerbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi), [powerquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerquery), [m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m), and [powerbi-datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-datasource).

Any questions related to a Power BI data source are either a question about PowerQuery (how to use the tool) or a question specifically about the PowerQuery language (M). There is never a case where a question about a Power BI data source is not inherently a question about PowerQuery.

**Tag Suggestion**

Burninate [powerbi-datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-datasource) (or at least mark it as a synonym of [powerquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerquery)).

- 93% of [powerbi-datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-datasource) is also tagged [powerbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi).
- While only 8% of [powerbi-datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-datasource) is also tagged [powerquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerquery), [powerquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerquery) is a larger tag (~10x more questions) and has a 1:1 overlap by definition.
- [powerquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerquery) has an existing tag definition ([powerbi-datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi-datasource) does not).

Definitely open to suggestions and feedback on this, but I wanted to post on Meta because I am passionate about organizing this corner of SO content, and I am still pretty far from being able to suggest a tag synonym by privilege.